# How can an Android app detect other applications using the microphone

Tags: android

Is there a way to determine if any applications are using a given
AudioSource? Best would be to get the list of applications currently
using an AudioSource.

This could be used by a VoIP application to know if another
application is recording the call.

Comment: could you please get more in detail? User A <-> User B, both have different devices ? And you want to know, if User A uses an AudioSource? We need more information :).